# Problem understandig lambda-calculus incompatible problem.

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

Let $K \equiv \lambda xy.x$ and $S \equiv \lambda xyz.xz(yz)$. Show that S and K are incompatible.

The solution goes like:

Let $S=K$ and $I \equiv \lambda x.x$, we have to show that all terms are equal. Since  $S=K$ we have $SIMI=KIMI$ for any terms M.

$KIMI=(\lambda xy.x)(\lambda x.x)MI = (\lambda yx.x) (M)I=\lambda x.x I=II=I$ (I understand this.)

and

$SIMI=II(MI)=I(MI)=MI$   (This is the reduction I don't understand, specially the first step.)

Thus, we have I=MI. Now, let $M \equiv \lambda x.N$, then we have $I=N$ for all terms N, and we are done.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is just 3 one-step reductions, resulting in substituting $I$, $M$, and $I$ for $x$, $y$, and $z$ respectively into the definition of $S$:
$$
\begin{array}
& SIMI &= (\lambda xyz.xz(yz))\ I M I \quad & [\text{by definition of }S]\\ 
& = I I (M I) & [\text{3 arguments substituted}] \\
&= (I I) (M I) & [\text{implicitly understood parens added}] \\ 
&= I (M I) \\
&= M I
\end{array}
$$